# Javascript performance script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, response

I have 2 Javascripts scripts for 2 purposes. One of them works like a charm, the other, turns my browser slow and hard tou use.

Both scripts make a HTTP request to a PHP file on a remote server every X seconds.

1. One script receive values and displays them - This one works fine evene every second (the browser doesn't slow down)
2. The other receive values (1 or 0) to hide or show small images acording to the state, 0 or 1.

---- The script that receives values and is OK ----

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
 var refreshId = setInterval(function() { $( "#var_3" ).load( "getvalue.php?var=var_3.VALUE&type=0&round=1&dec=1" ); }, 1000);
 var refreshId = setInterval(function() { $( "#var_4" ).load( "getvalue.php?var=var_4.VALUE&type=0&round=1&dec=1" ); }, 1000); 
 var refreshId = setInterval(function() { $( "#var_5" ).load( "getvalue.php?var=var_5.VALUE&type=0&round=1&dec=1" ); }, 1000);
 var refreshId = setInterval(function() { $( "#var_0" ).load( "getvalue.php?var=var_0.VALUE&type=0&round=1&dec=1" ); }, 1000);
 var refreshId = setInterval(function() { $( "#var_1" ).load( "getvalue.php?var=var_1.VALUE&type=0&round=1&dec=1" ); }, 1000);
</script>

<span id="var_3">###</span>
<span id="var_4">###</span>
<span id="var_5">###</span>
<span id="var_0">###</span>
<span id="var_1">###</span>
```

Now the script that makes my browser suffer and I can't almost use the browser:

```
<script>
function GetEstado(para1) {

jQuery.extend
(
   {
       getValues: function(url) 
       {
           var result = null;
           $.ajax(
               {
                   url: url,
                   type: 'get',
                   dataType: 'html',
                   async: false,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function(data) 
                   {
                       result = data;
                   }
               }
           );
          return result;
       }
   }
);

   VARZ = $.getValues("getvalue.php?var="+para1+"&type=1");
   if (VARZ == 1) {
    document.getElementById(para1).style.display = "inline";
   } else {
    document.getElementById(para1).style.display = "none";
   }
};



setInterval(function() { GetEstado("OUT_39"); }, 5000);
setInterval(function() { GetEstado("OUT_31"); }, 5000);
setInterval(function() { GetEstado("OUT_40"); }, 5000);

HTML
<div id="OUT_39" style="display: inline"><img src="img/valv1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 544px; left: 397px;"></div>
<div id="OUT_41" style="display: inline"><img src="img/valv1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 244px; left: 297px;"></div>
<div id="OUT_40" style="display: inline"><img src="img/valv1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 44px; left: 17px;"></div>
```

Is there any way to make this script diferent and more faster like the first one?

Comment: Use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), so it won't block the UI.

Comment: Firstly the problem in the second example is your use of `async: false`. Remove it. Secondly, **do not use AJAX polling**. Even if the first example works now, it definitely won't when you've got even just a few users. Change your server to use WebSockets if you need to keep the client and server in close sync

Comment: As above: `async: false` - `$().load()` will use ajax - ie *asynchronous* - your $.ajax call is not a valid recreation of `$().load()` as it's **not asynchronous** - so the browser has to stop all activities while the call is made and wait until it's completed before it can continue (continue with the next call which locks the browser and waits).

Comment: How can i make a $().load() "version" of this second script?

Comment: Remove `async: false,`.  That's all.

Comment: freedomn-m - I did, it does not work with async: true,
:(